# GLSL - Blending colors based on max color value with a white background

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader, pixi.js

I have a shader that I'm working on for a 2D animation (in pixi.js for what it's worth). The shader is almost right, but just a little off. The problem is I want a white background.

[image]

The shader logic is as follows. We want to draw 3 colored circles, that have a nice radial alpha gradient. The circles should move randomly about the scene. This all works nicely.

When the circles would "overlap", we want to blend the colors by simply taking the max of each color channel. For instance (255, 0, 0) blends with (0, 0, 255) to create (255, 0, 255). This works as well.

The issue is the black background. I want to background to be white!. Thus, all the circles should look partially transparent on a white background. Here's the code for the shader.

```c
precision mediump float;

uniform vec2 uResolution;
uniform float uTime;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

// Permutation table. This is just a random jumble of all numbers 0-255,
// repeated two times to avoid wrapping the index at 512, where we get the
// same locations as at 0.
vec3 permute(vec3 x) { return mod(((x*34.0)+1.0)*x, 289.0); }

float snoise(vec2 v){
  const vec4 C = vec4(0.211324865405187,  // (3.0-sqrt(3.0))/6.0
                      0.366025403784439,  // 0.5*(sqrt(3.0)-1.0)
                     -0.577350269189626,  // -1.0 + 2.0 * C.x
                      0.024390243902439); // 1.0 / 41.0
// First corner
  vec2 i  = floor(v + dot(v, C.yy) );
  vec2 x0 = v -   i + dot(i, C.xx);

// Other corners
  vec2 i1;
  //i1.x = step( x0.y, x0.x ); // x0.x > x0.y ? 1.0 : 0.0
  //i1.y = 1.0 - i1.x;
  i1 = (x0.x > x0.y) ? vec2(1.0, 0.0) : vec2(0.0, 1.0);
  // x0 = x0 - 0.0 + 0.0 * C.xx ;
  // x1 = x0 - i1 + 1.0 * C.xx ;
  // x2 = x0 - 1.0 + 2.0 * C.xx ;
  vec4 x12 = x0.xyxy + C.xxzz;
  x12.xy -= i1;

// Permutations
  i = mod(i, 289.0); // Avoid truncation effects in permutation
  vec3 p = permute( permute( i.y + vec3(0.0, i1.y, 1.0 ))
    + i.x + vec3(0.0, i1.x, 1.0 ));

  vec3 m = max(0.5 - vec3(dot(x0,x0), dot(x12.xy,x12.xy), dot(x12.zw,x12.zw)), 0.0);
  m = m*m ;
  m = m*m ;

// Gradients: 41 points uniformly over a line, mapped onto a diamond.
// The ring size 17*17 = 289 is close to a multiple of 41 (41*7 = 287)

  vec3 x = 2.0 * fract(p * C.www) - 1.0;
  vec3 h = abs(x) - 0.5;
  vec3 ox = floor(x + 0.5);
  vec3 a0 = x - ox;

// Normalise gradients implicitly by scaling m
// Approximation of: m *= inversesqrt( a0*a0 + h*h );
  m *= 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * ( a0*a0 + h*h );

// Compute final noise value at P
  vec3 g;
  g.x  = a0.x  * x0.x  + h.x  * x0.y;
  g.yz = a0.yz * x12.xz + h.yz * x12.yw;
  return 130.0 * dot(m, g);
}

vec4 getColor4(vec2 uv, vec3 color, float alpha, float r){
  // float r = random(color);
  float speed = 0.25;

  float noiseX = snoise(vec2(uTime * speed, r)); // Perlin noise for x
  float noiseY = snoise(vec2(r, uTime * speed)); // Perlin noise for y

  // scale and shift the noise to get it into the range [0, 0.5] for each coordinate
  vec2 pt = vec2(0.25 + 0.25 * noiseX, 0.25 + 0.25 * noiseY);

  // the radius of the circle
  float radius = 0.2;
  // hardness of the circle (-radius to radius)
  float hardness = 0.0;
  // the distance between the coordinate and the center of the circle
  float l = length(uv - pt);
  // the smoothstep function returns 0.0 if l is less than radius and 1.0 if l is greater than radius
  float s = smoothstep(radius, hardness, l);
  // float s = 1. - step(radius, l);

  // mix the colors (this gives the gradient effect)
  return mix(vec4(0,0,0,0), vec4(color, 1.), s);
}

vec4 maxBlend(vec4 c1, vec4 c2) {
  return vec4(max(c1[0], c2[0]), max(c1[1], c2[1]), max(c1[2], c2[2]), 1);
}

void main()
{
  vec2 uv = vTextureCoord;

  vec3 red = vec3(255, 0, 0) / 255.;
  vec3 blue = vec3(0, 0, 255) / 255.;
  vec3 green = vec3(0, 255, 0) / 255.;

  vec4 rcol = getColor4(uv, red, 1., 0.);
  vec4 bcol = getColor4(uv, blue, 1., 1.);
  vec4 gcol = getColor4(uv, green, 1., 2.);
  vec4 col = maxBlend(bcol, rcol);

  col = maxBlend(col, gcol);
  gl_FragColor = col;
}
```

The `snoise` function can be ignored - it's working as intended.

I tried changing `return mix(vec4(0,0,0,0), vec4(color, 1.), s);` to `return mix(vec4(1,1,1,0), vec4(color, 1.), s);` as the return value for `getColor4`, but this fails, since it breaks the `maxBlend` functionality.

Perhaps there's a way to achieve the desired effect without "stacking" the `getColor4` function with `maxBlend` in this way? Or a way to color-correct at the end?